# autoscan Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE [^\}]*}/

Tags: perl, autotools, autoconf, automake

when running autoscan 2.69 (2012 release) I got this error message.  It is a simple error in the perl code. autoscan is part of autoconf.

Comment: it was a warning, not an error message (though it will become an error in a future version of perl)

Answer (score 1):

I edited the file: /usr/bin/autoscan (only changed line 361) the modified version:

```
360       s/#.*//;
361       s/\$\{[^\}]*\}//g;
362       s/@[^@]*@//g;
```

This seems to get rid of the warning (future will be error) message.

Comment: please create a proper [bug-report at the autoconf project](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html#bug), including your fix. [so] is not necessarily a good place to collect fixes for various widly-used software...

Comment: I have reported to the autoscan email.  I like the autotools system and I am learning it.

Comment: I get this warning too, a lot, and I've ignored it because things still seemed to work... I'm sure it's a bug in autoscan.